# how to use like keyword in sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a sql query shown below i want to use the variables streetname, keyword1,radius and perform the sql query using like keyword but their is some problem with query syntax can anyone help

```
  protected void CreateXML(string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "data source='192.168.0.221';user id='sa';password='$sql123';persist security info=False;initial catalog=Test;Connect Timeout=100; Min Pool Size=100; Max Pool Size=500";
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        sqlda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Id,Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,Lng, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (12.925432/57.2958) ) * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (77.591667/57.2958) ) + SIN( 12.925432/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) AS distance FROM Business_Details where( (distance < '"+radius+"')and(StreetName like '%streetname%')and (Keyword like '%keyword1%') )ORDER BY distance";
        sqlda.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        sqlda.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: What error do you get? I don't see a syntax error in your query, and I've had Toad parse it, it didn't mind your query.

Comment: No its not error, but the issue is variables streetname and keyword1 are obtained from other functions ,streetname and keyword1 has some value , those two variables are not static they are dynamic they are passed from textbox entries.

Comment: I made changes to query its working fine, i changed the syntax 
"...like '%" + streetname + "%') and (keyword like '%" + keyword1 + "%') )....." thanks for reply.

Comment: this is not recommended! I've added a comment to the answer you've accepted which improves security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to do this -

```
"...like '%" + streetname + "%') and (keyword like '%" + keyword1 + "%') )..."
```

EDIT: As Rob mentions in the comment, editing this answer for better security -

```
"...like '%' + @streetname + '%') and (keyword like '%' + @keyword1 + '%') )..."
```

Then you need to add these parameters to the command object -

```
command.Parameters.Add("@streetname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@streetname"].Value = streetname;
command.Parameters.Add("@keyword1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters["@keyword1"].Value = keyword1;
```

Comment: Thanks sachin i edited code as you suggested its working fine thank you very much

Comment: @Matti Virkunnen yes! @Sachin Shanbhag, please improve this answer by changing it to use variables. In this case "...like '%' + @streetname + '%') and (keyword like '%' + @keyword1 + '%') )...", then add the code that add those variables to the SqlCommand. Right now, you're promoting a bad practice. Oh and mind those quotes if you decide to change this!

Answer (score 0):

If you get no error message and the query just doesn't return any data, you have to concatenate the query string like Sachin Shanbhag already said before me.

But if you really get a message that there is an error in your SQL syntax, I don't think it's because of the LIKE keyword because technically, this syntax is correct:

```
Keyword like '%keyword1%'
```

If you really have an error in your syntax, it's probably because of the "ACOS(COS(x) * 24534" stuff. Try to leave that away for the first step and just do "SELECT * FROM ...".